# Verificar si $_GET['id'] está vacío

Tags: php, mysql, apache

Intenté con este código verificar que si en la url que intenta buscar el usuario http://localhost/personajes/Nombre_Apellido

Que si la url no tiene ningún Nombre_Apellido, como si estuviese algo así http://localhost/personajes/
no verifique nada y le diga al usuario que tenga que usar un Nombre_Apellido

```
<?php
require 'includes/init.php';
    //Verificar si existe
    if(isset($_GET['id'])){
        //Verificar si esta vacia
        if(empty($_GET['id'])){
            //Lo que sucede si esta vacio
        }else{
            //Lo que sucede si no esta vacio
            $user_data = $user_obj->find_user_by_id($_GET['id']);
        }
    } 

?>
```

Pero obtengo este error

```
Notice: Undefined Variable: User_data
```

Comment: Faltan algunas llaves de cerrar {

Comment: Y de donde se supone que es `User_data` ?? En ningún lado aparece dicha variable...

Comment: ¿Donde se supone que está la función `find_user_by_id()`? en el init ??, siendo asi, de donde viene `User_data` entonces ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verifica las funciones por separado

> ```
> if( isset($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['id']) ) {
>     echo "Hay info, id=".$_GET['id'];
> } else {
>     echo "No hay info";
> }
> ```

Comment: ¿Cómo es que esto responde a la pregunta del OP? si el error dice claramente que el problema es la variable `User_data` que no aparece en ningún lado del código del OP. Es más, hasta donde veo, solo has unificado las validaciones del OP...

Answer (score 0):

Primero usa una función y luego usas la otra, de la siguiente forma. Primero verificas si existe tu variable y luego verificas si esta vacía.

```
<?php
require 'includes/init.php';
    //Verificar si existe
    if(isset($_GET['id'])){
        //Verificar si esta vacia
        if(empty($_GET['id'])){
            //Lo que sucede si esta vacio
        }else{
            //Lo que sucede si no esta vacio
            $user_data = $user_obj->find_user_by_id($_GET['id']);
        }
    }else{

    {
        
   
    

?>
```

Comment: Todavía no funciona, tengo este error, ```syntax error, unexpected end of file in``` seguro es por no cerrar el else al final, intenté cerrarlo y tengo este error ```Notice: Undefined Variable: User_data In``` si el usuario no ingresa nada

Comment: Amigo edita tu publicación para ver como te quedo, y poder ayudarte

Comment: Ya está cambiado.

Comment: De casualidad el error no es mas largo o no tiene mas información ?, te dice que la variable no esta definida, pero yo si la veo definida.

Comment: `User_data` es otra variable, que no está en el código expuesto.

Comment: Bro tienes toda la razón, no me había fijado